# MantineUI - Autocomplete: Customed item component not show up

Tags: reactjs, mantine

As I was trying to follow Mantine UI docs to create a customed item, but seem things didn't work out as I expected.
Here my code:

```
interface SearchProps extends SelectItemProps {
  name: string;
}

const itemSearch = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, SearchProps>(
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  ({ value, name, ...others }: SearchProps, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} {...others}>
      <Group>
        <Text>{name}</Text>
        <Text>{value}</Text>
      </Group>
    </div>
  )
);

function Search(props: Omit<ComponentProps<typeof Autocomplete>, "data">) {
  const { products, q } = useLoaderData() as Awaited<ReturnType<typeof loader>>;
  const submit = useSubmit();

  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
  const productsData = products?.map(
    (product: { name: string; _id: string }) => ({
      name: product.name,
      value: product._id,
      label: product.name,
    })
  );
  console.log(productsData);
  return (
    <Form role="search" ref={inputRef} method="GET" className={props.className}>
      <Autocomplete
        itemComponent={itemSearch}
        styles={{
          input: {
            borderRadius: "20px !important",
          },
        }}
        defaultValue={q as string}
        type="search"
        aria-label="Search products"
        placeholder="Search "
        onChange={() => {
          const isFirstSearch = q == null;
          submit(new FormData(inputRef?.current as HTMLFormElement), {
            replace: !isFirstSearch,
          });
        }}
        // icon={<IconSearch size="1rem" stroke={2} />}
        icon={<Loader size="xs" />}
        name="q"
        data={productsData ? productsData : []}
      />
    </Form>
  );
}

export default Search;
```

But, if I replace the productsdata with sample data from Mantine docs, The customed just displayed really good,
here the sample code from the docs:

```
const charactersList = [
  {
    image: 'https://img.icons8.com/clouds/256/000000/futurama-bender.png',
    label: 'Bender Bending Rodríguez',
    description: 'Fascinated with cooking, though has no sense of taste',
  },

  {
    image: 'https://img.icons8.com/clouds/256/000000/futurama-mom.png',
    label: 'Carol Miller',
    description: 'One of the richest people on Earth',
  },
  {
    image: 'https://img.icons8.com/clouds/256/000000/homer-simpson.png',
    label: 'Homer Simpson',
    description: 'Overweight, lazy, and often ignorant',
  },
  {
    image: 'https://img.icons8.com/clouds/256/000000/spongebob-squarepants.png',
    label: 'Spongebob Squarepants',
    description: 'Not just a sponge',
  },
];

const data = charactersList.map((item) => ({ ...item, value: item.label }));

interface ItemProps extends SelectItemProps {
  color: MantineColor;
  description: string;
  image: string;
}

const AutoCompleteItem = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, ItemProps>(
  ({ description, value, image, ...others }: ItemProps, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} {...others}>
      <Group noWrap>
        <Avatar src={image} />

        <div>
          <Text>{value}</Text>
          <Text size="xs" color="dimmed">
            {description}
          </Text>
        </div>
      </Group>
    </div>
  )
);
```

I wonder why is this happening?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

as exemple, my code

```
<Autocomplete
                    style={{
                        maxWidth: '373px',
                        margin: '0 auto',
                    }}
                    placeholder="SEARCH"
                    data={state.venues}
                    value={state.inputText}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    maxDropdownHeight="200px"
                    limit={state.venues.length}
                    nothingFound={
                        state.noResults && (
                            <Box
                                style={{
                                    textAlign: 'left',
                                    padding: '10px',
                                    textTransform: 'uppercase',
                                    fontFamily: 'MaisonNeue-Mono, maison-mono',
                                    fontSize: '16px',
                                }}
                            >
                                <Text>No results</Text>
                            </Box>
                        )
                    }
                    rightSection={state.loading && <Loader size="xs" variant="dots" />}
                    itemComponent={itemComponent}
                />
```

and each item

```
const itemComponent = (item) => {
    const handlePress = () => {
        setSecondModalOpen(true)
        setState({
            itemSubmitted: true,
            noResults: false,
            modalOpen: true,
            selectedVenue: { value: item.value, id: item.id },
        })
    }
    return (
        <>
            <Box
                style={{
                    padding: '10px',
                }}
                onClick={() => handlePress()}
            >
                <Text style={ fontSize: '16px', textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>
                    {item.value}
                </Text>
            </Box>
            <Box
                style={{
                    padding: '10px',
                }}
            >
                {state.venues[state.venues.length - 1].id !== item.id && (
                    <Box style={{ borderBottom: '1px solid #E3E3E3' }}></Box>
                )}
            </Box>
        </>
    )
}
```